# Hide and show linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have one linearlayout and have also a few button inside it.I want make it visible when touch and invisible when touch it again.

How can i make it??

Comment: You can do it using .setVisibility. But How will user know the button is there while it would be invisible?

Answer (score 33):

```
LinearLayout one = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.one);
one.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I suggest  that you use GONE insteady of INVISIBLE in the onclick event because with
    `View.GONE` the place for the layout will not be visible and the application will not appear to have unused space in it unlike the `View.INVISIBLE` that will leave the gap that is intended for the the layout

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm. Then I used `View.VISIBLE` to make mine reappear.

Answer (score 3):

Add a boolean on your code

```
boolean flag = false;
```

then add **android:clickable = true** on your linear layout on xml

then use this code for reference

```
your_linear_layout = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (flag){
        // means true
        your_linear_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        flag = false; 
        }
        else{
        your_linear_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) 
        flag = true;
        }

    }

};
```

Havent tried this yet but this should work..

Cheers

Comment: Use view.isShown() or getVisibility() and you wouldnt need that Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

add [setOnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) to linearLayout get touch events as :

```
linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

         // show-hide view here

        return true;
      }

     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

         // show-hide view here

        return true;
      }

   return false;
  }
});
```

for making View visible use `yourview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and for Invisible use `yourview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: i dont understand about yourview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and yourview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE).can you explain

Comment: @KokoKrunch :  yourview mean your view (like linarlayout,buttons,textviews,...) which you want to show/hide for example `linarlayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` or linarlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: did i need to put every button that are located in linearlayout or i just need put only linearlayout at 'show-hide view'

Comment: @KokoKrunch : if you add show/hide on linearlayout click then when u hide it then how user click on it second time . i think u will need to hide one by one views from layout or show/hide linearlayout on any other view click

Answer (score 0):

You should user

Invisible -: `mButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Vsible -:    `mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Put this code in onclick listner of button With checking if condition.